# Webpack 4 + Angular 10 custom webpack: search and replace loader not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

So I'm trying to use a custom webpack config in my Angular 10.x app where I want to remove 'data-test' attributes from my templates during compilation, so the production code does not contain any e2e selector references. For this, I'm using the custom webpack builder (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) with a custom webpack config. I'm loading the config in the `angular.json` like this:

```
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.ts",
              "mergeStrategies": {
                "externals": "append"
              }
            },
```

And the webpack config looks like this:

```
import { CustomWebpackBrowserSchema, TargetOptions } from '@angular-builders/custom-webpack';
import { EnvironmentType, getEnumValues } from '@enum-package/core/enumeration';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

export default (config: webpack.Configuration, options: CustomWebpackBrowserSchema, targetOptions: TargetOptions) => {
  const env: EnvironmentType =
    <EnvironmentType>(
      getEnumValues(EnvironmentType).find(environmentType =>
        targetOptions.configuration?.toLowerCase().includes(environmentType.toLowerCase()),
      )
    ) ?? EnvironmentType.DEVELOPMENT;

  if (config.module?.rules) {
    // Remove E2E testing attributes from production code
    if (env === EnvironmentType.PRODUCTION) {
      const testSelectorRegex = new RegExp(/data-test="(.*)"|@HostBinding\('attr.data-test'\)(.*);/g);
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|ts|html)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        options: {
          search: testSelectorRegex.source,
          replace: match => {
            console.log(`Replace E2E selector '${match}'.`);
            return ' ';
          },
          flags: 'g',
        },
      });
    }
  }

  return config;
};
```

The `search-replace-loader` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) is what takes care of replacing the actual attributes from the templates. While running the `ng build` command, I can actually see that the replace itself works, since the `Replace E2E selector '${match}'.` is actually running and I can see the tags that I want to remove being logged during compilation.

For some reason when running the app from the `dist` folder after compilation, the tags are still in place when I inspect the DOM in my browser.

Am I missing something? Is there a build step before or after running this webpack loader that does not use the replaced source code? Does this have anything to do with the Ivy build engine that we're using?

Comment: I haven't seen that way of writing rules before. have you tried using the `use` property? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too, but gives the same result. The way this is written is actually just an alias to the `use` property. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleloader

Comment: When you change "test" to the following value: `test: /\.(html)$/,`, does it still match? It might only be an issue for html files and that Angular is not passing it through webpack by default.